# What is the nature of the diagonalizing matrix of certain types of matrices?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics

Suppose I have a matrix, A of order n. I want to diagonalize it. To diagonalize, I will have to evaluate the eigenvalues of the matrix and the corresponding eigenvectors. Then I will have to form a matrix, P, using these eigenvectors.
My question is what will be the nature of this matrix P when the nature of the initial matrix A has been specified to be real symmetric? Also, what will be the nature of P if A is Hermitian?

Comment: What specifically do you want to know? A certain character of the matrix? For example, will the answer 'if A is Hermitian then P is Unitary' satisfy you?

Comment: Play around with making matrices and computing their eigenvalues/eigenvectors in Matlab or Octave using the 'eig' command. You can do this online at https://octave-online.net/ You will be able to see the pattern and come to the correct conclusion yourself.

Comment: @OfekGillon, that is what I want to know.  Tha nature of the matrix.

Comment: @NickAlger Thank you for your advice. The things I don't know how to use it. I will learn that in near future, but it would be helpful if I get the answer here.

Comment: @SamapanBhadury from what field are the matrix's elements? $\mathbb{R} , \mathbb{C}$, or a general field $\mathbb{F}$?

Comment: 1. The matrix is real and symmetric.
2. The matrix is Hermitian.
Also, if possible, I would like to know all the other possibilities too. e.g. for a real anti-symmetric matrix, anti-hermitian matrix etc.

Comment: Real symmetric matrices *are* Hermitian. They are just a special case with all the imaginary parts of the numbers equal to zero. Almost all the "interesting" properties of real symmetric matrices are also true for all Hermitian matrices.